# Facebook API Not Returning Post Link and Picture

Tags: c#, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I use to call the following URL:

```
  https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/me?access_token=<non_expiring_token>&debug=all&fields=id%2Cname%2Cposts.limit(3)&format=json&method=get&pretty=0&suppress_http_code=1
```

...to generate Facebook recent JSON.  However, it seems to no longer be including the post link and picture per message.  The JSON is returning the following format:

```
{  
   "id":"################################",
   "name":"PageName",
   "posts":{  
      "data":[  
         {  
            "message":"blah blah blah blah",
            "created_time":"2015-08-18T15:33:55+0000",
            "id":"255265457833877_1175667159127031"
         },
         {  
            "message":"blah blah blah blah",
            "created_time":"2015-08-05T15:18:54+0000",
            "id":"255265457833877_1168482559845491"
         },
         {  
            "message":"blah blah blah blah",
            "created_time":"2015-07-22T17:12:45+0000",
            "id":"255265457833877_1160836887276725"
         }
      ],
      "paging":{  
         "previous":"...",
         "next":"..."
      }
   }
}
```

When it use to return in the following format:

http://codeshare.io/EvIdN

Any ideas of what may have changed?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: _“Any ideas of what may have changed?”_ – could that kind of information be found in the _change log_ perhaps …?  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4_changes – “declarative fields”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the new graph api 2.4 version , you need to specify the fields you want , or it will return only basic fields such as id .
You could modify you request to use v2.3 by modifying the version in your URL (v2.3 instead of v2.4)
and it would produce the expected response .

Or if you need to use the latest version you have to specify the fields like this
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/me/posts?access_token={Your Token}&fields=message,link,picture

Comment: Thanks, that did the job!  I overlooked the field change in the v2.4 documentation.